# How can I pass a jquery value from a selected dropdown list to a variable in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, laravel-5.1

I have created field for (price) in the controller class like so.

```
   protected $fields = [
        'tag' => '',
        'title' => '',
        'location' => '',
        'property_type' => '',
        'residence_name' => '',
        'bedroom_no' => '',
        'price' => '',
        'lease' => 0,
    ];
```

I have also created a column (price) in my table for migration like so.

```
Schema::table('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->string('location');
    $table->string('property_type');
    $table->string('residence_name');
    $table->string('bedroom_no');
    $table->string('price');
    $table->boolean('lease');

});
```

other fields are saved in the database because they are text input fields.
Here is a working sample code for location input field being saved in the database:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="location" class="col-md-3 control-label">
  Location / City
  </label>
   <div class="col-md-8">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="location" placeholder=""
       id="location" value="{{ $location }}">
 </div>
</div>
```

And here is the code for price dropdown, I want get the value of var price from jQuery and then pass it to the `$price` var in Laravel:

```
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="price" class="col-md-3 control-label">
   Price
  </label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <select class="form-control" id="price" value="{{ $price }}">
    <option>10,000 - 15,000</option>
    <option>15,000 - 20,000</option>
    <option>20,000 - 25,000</option>
    <option>30,000 - 50,000</option>
    <option>50,000 and Above</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
```

with a jQuery script code to accept the input from user

```
<script>
$("#price").change(function () {
   var price = $(this).val();
   alert(price);
});
</script>
```

Comment: have you ever heared about forms?

Comment: I am currently using forms. I got some values from input type text. But getting value from a select dropdown is my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Add to your `<select>` tag a `name` attribute `price` and to every `<option>` tag attribute `value` with the value you desire.

```
<select class="form-control" id="price" name="price">
    <option value="10,000 - 15,000">10,000 - 15,000</option>
    <option value="15,000 - 20,000">15,000 - 20,000</option>
    <option value="20,000 - 25,000">20,000 - 25,000</option>
    <option value="30,000 - 50,000">30,000 - 50,000</option>
    <option value="50,000 and Above">50,000 and Above</option>
</select>
```

You don't need anything else. This is how HTML forms work.

The value is attached to the name and you will be able to get it later with:

`$request->input('price');`
The argument you pass to `$request->input` is the name parameter of your input/select/checkbox/radio element in your form and it will be equal to whatever `value` was selected.

Remove the javascript, because it's not needed in your case.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="price" class="col-md-3 control-label">
   Price
  </label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <select class="form-control" id="price">
    <option value="10,000 - 15,000">10,000 - 15,000</option>
    <option value="15,000 - 20,000">15,000 - 20,000</option>
    <option value="20,000 - 25,000">20,000 - 25,000</option>
    <option value="30,000 - 50,000">30,000 - 50,000</option>
    <option value="50,000 and Above">50,000 and Above</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
```

And in jquery

```
$("#price").on("change", function () {
    var price = $(this).val(); 
    alert(price);
    //Here you can use ajax to call php function
    $.ajax({
        url : <your_function_path>,
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
            price : price
        },
        success : function(ret_data) {
        }
    });
});
```

And then in your php function get value through Request object with "input" or "get" function

for eg. Suppose you have class called ABC and function called PQR

```
class ABC extends Controller {
    public function PQR(Request $request) {
        $price = $request->get('price');
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: this does not pass any value to php. you only copied back the code i posted and then pasted it back. i need the value of price from the jquery code to be passed to php, so that it will be saved in database. here is one sample that worked for a text input.

    <div class="form-group">
  <label for="location" class="col-md-3 control-label">
    Location / City
  </label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="location" placeholder="e.g Makati City"
           id="location" value="{{ $location }}">
  </div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you can save the text input fields in the database, so I suppose you know how to do form submissions in HTML, set up a post route in Laravel, capture the input in your controller, and then save to your model.

If that's the case, and the only problem is the select dropdown, then it seems like you have forgotten the name attribute on the select tag and the value attributes on the option tags.

If you want to set a default value in the dropdown, like I guess you are trying to due with `value={{ $price }}`, then you should use the `selected` attribute instead.

```
<select class="form-control" id="price" name="price">
    <option value='10,000 - 15,000'>10,000 - 15,000</option>
    <option value='15,000 - 20,000'>15,000 - 20,000</option>
    <option value='20,000 - 25,000' selected='selected'>20,000 - 25,000</option>
    <option value='30,000 - 50,000'>30,000 - 50,000</option>
    <option value='50,000+'>50,000 and Above</option>
</select>
```